# When does getaddrinfo return more than one sockaddr struct in the list?

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I am working with some code I found and I am trying to understand the ***for loop*** logic in this.

It seems like the for loop is not being used and it is always going to break. So I am not understanding what sort of information is returned from getaddrinfo() that would cause this to loop over again and check for something?

Question: Basically what is this for loop trying to accomplish? It seems to me it is just checking that list is not NULL because no loop is occurring, ever.

```
tcp_ctx* tcp_new_ctx(INT family, CHAR *host, CHAR *port) {
    struct addrinfo *list = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *e = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    tcp_ctx         *c = NULL;
    WSADATA         wsa;
    INT             on = 1;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa);

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family = family;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // try to resolve network address for host
    //list contains linked list of addrinfo structs containing information on the host
    if (getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &list) != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    c = tcp_alloc(sizeof(tcp_ctx));

    // Traverse linked list from getaddr info
    for (e = list; e != NULL; e = e->ai_next) {
        if (family == AF_INET) {
            memcpy(&c->v4, e->ai_addr, e->ai_addrlen);
            c->ai_addr = (SOCKADDR*)&c->v4;
        } else if (family == AF_INET6) {
            memcpy(&c->v6, e->ai_addr, e->ai_addrlen);
            c->ai_addr = (SOCKADDR*)&c->v6;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
        c->ai_addrlen = e->ai_addrlen;
        // create socket and event for signalling
        c->s = socket(family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (c->s != SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // ensure we can reuse same port later
            setsockopt(c->s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (CHAR*)&on, sizeof(on));
        }
        break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(list);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: The loop looks somewhere between superfluous and broken. (It only cares about the first address. If that first address isn't IPv4 or IPv6, the code will break....but that's exceedingly unlikely in today's internet.)

Comment: FWIW, I agree with you that the `for` statement does nothing except verify that `list` is not equal to `NULL`. The loop would make sense if the goal was to find an IPv4 address, while skipping IPv6 addresses. But that's not what the loop is doing.

Comment: What would be in the list? Other IP address to the address it did getaddrinfo() on? If I understood what the list getaddrinfo() was supposed to return looked like with multiple links, then I could probably get this fixed. However I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What would be in the list?**

The following quote is from the [man page of `getaddrinfo` of glibc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gai_strerror.3.html), but AFAIK it applies equally to the Windows version:

> There are several reasons why the linked list may have more than one
>          addrinfo structure, including: the network host is multihomed, accessible over multiple protocols (e.g., both AF_INET and AF_INET6); or
>          the same service is available from multiple socket types (one
>          SOCK_STREAM address and another SOCK_DGRAM address, for example).

So, basically the host could have multiple ways to contact it, and `getaddrinfo` is listing all (known) ways.  Note that the same man page further states:

> Normally, the application should try using the addresses in the order
>          in which they are returned.  The sorting function used within getaddrinfo() is defined in RFC 3484;

Of course, here too we don't know whether this also holds for the Windows implementation(s), but if it's specified in an [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) then that might be the case.

**What is this for loop trying to accomplish?**

As it stands you could remove the loop.  I think there might be a reason to keep  (= fix) it, though:  Consider the case where the first returned entry has a `family` of neither `AF_INET` nor `AF_INET6`.  The code in your questions then just fails (`return NULL;`), but there could be a later entry in the list which could have that family.

Comment: I generally stay away from the man pages but these seems to explain everything I needed to know. I understand what it is going to return now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The loop doesn't check the family of the first (or any) returned entry, which would be `e->ai_family`; it checks the _function parameter_ `family`, which is also put into `hints.ai_family`, requiring that all and any entries returned by gai must have that family, and thus if more than one all will be the same.